# Laravel5 - artisan down command trying to access database?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I've deployied a project on a new server. When i issue

`php artisan down`

i get

```
[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using pas
  sword: YES)
```

Why is it trying to access the database? Why root? I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

`Down` does not try to access database, tried myself, so you may have:

- A registered ServiceProvider trying to access it
- A Middleware trying to access it (if you run it via a web route); or
- Some other class doing it

Comment: Are Middlewares triggered by artisan, really?

Comment: Usually not, but if you do `Route::get('/down', { Artisan::call('down') })`, they may :)

Comment: You were close. I have a secondary DB connection in app/config/database.php. Apparently, artisan is trying to establish that connection even if it's not required.

Comment: Artisan will not try to do that, unless something else is being executed. Usually this is something ServiceProviders do. Try to disable all of the non-laravel ones and execute down.

Comment: Yeah, i confirm it's not an artisan thing. It's a global application issue, so i guess i should update question and title.